# Will jump starting a car work if starter is not working?

Tags: battery, starter

If starter is not working, will jump starting a car work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If the starter doesn't work, it won't start the car. More power isn't going to change that.

Comment: Paulster2 is correct, but the info might be more understandable this way: If the starter doesn't work _because the car's battery is providing insufficient electrical current_, then jumping can provide the electrical current so the starter operates. If, on the other hand, the starter doesn't work _because the starter has a mechanical or electrical fault_, then jumping won't help.